# Serverless query in synapse fails

Tags: azure-synapse

new to Synapse, built a pipeline to ingest data from on prem sql server to Data Lake gen 2 as a csv file.  Pipelines runs fine.  on the Data hub I can see my file.  In order to simplify things, i changed my source query to..  select top 10 PKId from myTable. I can right click and preview the data.

When I right click and select, select top 100 rows, i get a sql script.  I added a with statement.

```
    SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://sy     egen2fs/Raw/*.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0')
    WITH 
    (
    UserID int
    ) AS [result];
```

when I run the query, i get a header column, no data and the error...  Error handling external file: 'waitIOCompletion error. HRESULT = 0x80070005(offset = 0, bytes requested = 78).'. File/External table name: 'http

I have not created any databases or tables or views within synapse.  I am just trying to query the file.  I have found some articles on recreating a Master database Key...  but don't think that applies to me, since just tryinng to read file.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The underlying reason for the error is unclear, in general, the error message [WaitIOCompletion](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand.md#waitiocompletion-call-failed) indicates that the query failed while waiting to complete the IO operation that reads data from the Azure Data Lake.

Make sure that you can access this file. If your file is protected with SAS key or custom identity, you would need to set up server-level credentials for SQL login.  Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-single-csv-file#read-a-csv-file) to know more.

I have tried it in my lab and worked fine for me. Hear I included header as my file contains a **header row**.

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM OPENROWSET(
  BULK 'https://vnmoola0121adls2.blob.core.windows.net/container1/test/*.csv',
  FORMAT = 'CSV',
  PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
  HEADER_ROW = TRUE)
WITH 
(
 UserID int
) AS [result];
```

[image]

Comment: On the data hub, I can see my data lake storage where I can navigate to the folder where my csv lives, right click the file and preview.  In the data hub I also see my data lake storage as a linked service, where I can also navigate to my file, right click, preview and see my data.

I basically just created the synapse resource and didn't do anything to protect the file..  just imported it.

It also sounds like, I should not have to create a data base just to read a csv file.

Comment: In synapse, I can issue queries...  select 1 works, select SYSTEM_USER returns my login properly.  On the Data tab, I select my storage account, select the sub folder underneath (primary), right click manage access and can see the same user returned by "select system_user".

Comment: I was able to get this to work by explicitly giving permissions to the file I am trying to query, but I was thinking the file would inherit permissions on the folder where my pipeline creates the csv file.

At least I have narrowed my issue down to permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by explicitly giving permissions to the file I am trying to query, but I was thinking the file would inherit permissions on the folder where my pipeline creates the csv file.

At least I have narrowed my issue down to permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Understand access control helped me figure out permissions.  I assumed child files of my parent folder would inherit permissions by default.  They do not.  I had to update access control properties and set permissions for "default".