# Resolve Synapse Serverless: IO ERROR = 0x00000005 when querying parquet files with OPENROWSET (doesn't affect spark pools!)

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-lake

### Problem

I have a parquet file in Azure Data Lake storage.
I am trying to query it from Synapse Serverless using `OPENROWSET`:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://example.dfs.core.windows.net/container/path/to/file.parquet',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
```

The current configuration *worked* until recently.
Now it returns:

```
Error handling external file: 'IO request completed with an error. ERROR = 0x00000005'. File/External table name: 'https://example.dfs.core.windows.net/container/path/to/file.parquet'
```

What is the cause of this error? How can I troubleshoot it?

*Strangely*, the headers are returned, but the data is not. So Synapse is at least reading part of the Parquet file.

### Things that still work:

- Querying the file with a Synapse spark pool:

  ```
  %%pyspark
  df = spark.read.load('abfss://container@example.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/file.parquet', format='parquet')
  display(df.limit(10))
  ```
- Displaying the list of data lake files under `Data > Linked > Attached storage > Container > file.parquet`
- Verifying the linked service connection still works under `Manage > Linked services > service > Test connection` (works when testing both to the linked service, and to file path.)

### Configuration

- Linked service to azure storage (Synapse workspace default)
- Connection via AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime
- System assigned managed identity (with `Storage Blob Data Contributor` access)
- Managed private endpoint (approved)

### More Errors

If I try to query a CSV file with `OPENROWSET`, I get this error:

```
Error encountered while parsing data: 'waitIOCompletion error. HRESULT = 0x80070005(offset = 0, bytes requested = 728).'. Underlying data description: file 'https://example.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/file.csv'
```

Comment: This error resolved itself today without any change on my end. I think it must be a Synapse glitch. A similar experience was reported [here](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Changing-a-column-name-gives-an-error-in-powerbi-desktop/td-p/3506884).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using the OPENROWSET but I did not receive the erorr

[image]

- The error message "`WaitIOCompletion call failed`" means that there was an issue with the query while waiting for the completion of the operation that reads data from Azure Data Lake.
- The error message typically appears in this format: `"Error handlingexternal file: 'WaitIOCompletion call failed. HRESULT = ???'.File/External table name..."`
- Make sure that your storage is placed in the same region as
  serverless SQL pool.  verify there are no other workloads on the storage layer, such as uploading new files, that could saturate I/O requests.

The field **HRESULT** contains the result code.
The following error codes `ERROR = 0x00000005`, `HRESULT = 0x80070005`

The 'IO request completed with an error. `ERROR = 0x00000005`' error while handling external files in Azure Data Lake Storage.
The error message "`WaitIOCompletion call failed`"
suggests that there was a problem while waiting for the input/output (I/O) operation to finish when reading data from Azure Data Lake,A remote storage service provided by Microsoft Azure.

- In order to resolve the issue you can recreate the Synapse Serverless database.
- Recreate the database MASTER KEY.
- It's possible that simply recreating the MASTER KEY could resolve the issue.

And regarding the `HRESULT = 0x80070005`

- This error might happen when using the user identity authentication method,
- And this can be resolved when explicitly give permissions to the
  file.

**References:**

- SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70793530/serverless-query-in-synapse-fails)
- [WaitIOCompletion call
  failed](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand.md#waitiocompletion-call-failed)
- Microsoft Q&A  [Synapse SQL Serverless error: 'WaitIOCompletion call
  failed. HRESULT =
  0x8007000C'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/507920/synapse-sql-serverless-error-waitiocompletion-call)

Comment: The error resolved itself today without any change on my end. Seems to be a Synapse glitch.